# How to find wiggle sortable arrays? Did I misunderstand John L.s' answer?

Tags: algorithms, sorting

I have read following answer and question [How to wiggle sort an array in linear time complexity?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/125372/how-to-wiggle-sort-an-array-in-linear-time-complexity).

But while reading I came up with a question. I can't comment on answers yet, so I decided to make an extra question out of it.

John L. states that

> Call A wiggle-sorted if A0 < A1 > A2 < A3 > A4<...
> Call A wiggle-sortable if we can rearrange its entries so that it becomes wiggle-sorted. An array is always wiggle-sortable if all numbers in it are distinct. If all numbers are not distinct, the array may or may not be wiggle-sortable. For example, [1,2,2] is not wiggle-sortable while [1,1,2] is wiggle-sortable."

I understand that there is no possibility to wiggle sort [1, 2, 2] because for wiggle sorting values next to each other are not allowed to be even and the values at the even indexes have to be smaller than those at the odd indexes. So, [2, 1, 2] would not be allowed.

I am confused because further in John L.s' answer it is stated:

> Characterization of wiggle-sortable arrays. The following propositions are equivalent for a number array of size n.

> 1. A is wiggle-sortable of size n.
> 2. (Not too many medians) The number of medians of A
>    is no more than ⌈n/2⌉.
> 3. If we have just sorted A(in the usual sense), then wn(A) is wiggle-sorted.

If 1 and 2 are equivalent then 2 being true means 1 is true.
The median for [1, 2, 2] is 2, the number of medians is also 2.
⌈n/2⌉ is ⌈3/2⌉ = 2.
So 2. seems fulfilled to me but [1, 2, 2] is not wiggle-sortable.

John L.s' seems to be way better at math than me though, so maybe I did misunderstand something?

Comment: Probably some of the ceilings need to be floors. A proof of the equivalence would make all of that clear.

Comment: I am writing a big update to that answer, replacing median with mode probably.

Comment: BranAndSceolan, please come [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135245/chat-with-john-l) for a chat.

Comment: I would like to. Sadly I can't participate in the chat because I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: @JohnL. what are we going to do now? Wait till I have got enough reputation? That might take a while.

Comment: @BranAndSceolan, Sorry that I have not updated that answer yet. You can accept the answer below for now. Then you will be 8 reputation away from being able to join a chatroom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have identified an off-by-one error in that answer.

The correct statement for proposition $2$ should be the following.

> (Not too many medians)$\def \A{\mathcal A}$ The number of medians of $\A$ is no more than $⌈n/2⌉$. Furthermore, if $n$ is odd and the number of medians is $[n/2]$, the median must be the smallest number of $\A$.

Or, what is equivalent,

> Any number occurs at most $⌈n/2⌉$ times in $\A$. Furthermore, if $n$ is odd and a number occurs $⌈n/2⌉$ times, it must be the smallest number of $\A$.